# How can I sign in using Google to Emacs StackExchange to post questions

Tags: web-browser, w3m

I am able to browse the Emacs StackExchange site using Emacs with `M-x w3m b URL RET`

I wanted to try out posting questions and answers to the site using Emacs. The main hurdle I am facing is to sign in using my Google account. In a regular browser the *Sign in With Google* is a button. In w3m however, I see only *Google* text on which I can't hit <kbd>RET</kbd>.

I can try out posting Q&A only after crossing this hurdle... Any tips?

NOTE: If there are better alternatives that can solve my issue then those are welcome too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install `sx` from melpa with `M-x package-install RET sx RET`

it is on: https://github.com/vermiculus/sx.el

quoting the site:

> SX is a full-featured Stack Exchange mode for GNU Emacs 24+. Using the official API, it provides a versatile experience for the Stack Exchange network within Emacs itself.